# best practice of using VCS in composer projects

Tags: git, cakephp, version-control, composer-php

I have been writing applications in `CakePHP` which uses composer to install plugins and other repositories from `GitHub` and other sources.

Till now I use to add all `vendor/` files to Git repository which dramatically increase the repository size due to a lot of `composer` installs in the project.

As per best practice concerned while using `VCS`, `vendor/` directory is added in `.gitignore` file to prevent pushing to VCS repository.

In my `CakePHP` application, I require some sort of script which could not be found on `GitHub` or other sources. So, I created those script files in

```
vendor/anuj-tbe/
```

director. and in `composer.json` file, marked entry using

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "AnujTbe\\": "vendor/anuj-tbe",
    }
},
```

and also want to push the script files to VCS because it can not be downloaded later using composer.

**1. Is `vendor/` right place to put custom script files?**
**2. Can I just ignore vendor files except for my own directory?**

Comment: Why do you place files in the `vendor` directory that are not installed through composer? That's what other folders like `src` are for

Comment: I placed there to include in `autoload` and use via `namespace` in other parts of application. Also `src` directory of `CakePHP` contains models, controller, templates etc. Also there could be many `src` directories if plugins are used.

Comment: Why don't you use src for this, as you have done with the `App` namespace? The next run of `composer update` will remove the folder you manually created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for both of your two questions.

First, `vendor/` shouldn’t be tracked in VCS, and you can also refer the example [.gitignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/CakePHP.gitignore) for CakePHP.

Second, you can place the  script files in any place you like including under `vendor/anuj-tbe/`. So you just need to exclude v`endor/anuj-tbe` in `.gitignore`.

Steps as below to remove the `vendor/` from VCS while keeping `vendor/anuj-tbe/`.

```
# After adding your scripts in vendor/anuj-tbe/
git add .
git commit -m 'add scripts'
touch .gitignore
```

Make sure below contents are included in .gitignore:

```
vendor/*
!vendor/anuj-tbe
```

Continue with below commands:

```
git rm vendor/* --cached -r
git add .
git commit -m 'remove vendor in VCS except vendor/anuj-tbe'
```

Now except `vendor/anuj-tbe`, all the files and sub-folders in `vendor/` are ignored in VCS.

Answer (score 2):

Composer installs a `composer.lock` file which locks your dependencies to the last version that was installed. That means the next time you run `composer install` it's going to re-install the same dependencies. The benefit is that when you switch to a different computer and checkout the project and run `composer install` you get the same dependencies.

That means you don't need to commit the `vendor` folder to VCS. So add it to your `.gitignore` file.

### Archive your builds

When you build and deploy your Cake app to a web server it's going to include the `vendor` folder. That version of your Cake application is going to sit there for a long time. Maybe later in the future when you come back you need to work on it again, and maybe by chance a composer dependency is gone (i.e. the open source guy died, and now that package has disappeared). So you should keep archives of your production builds with the vendor folder so that you always have a copy of the dependencies that work with that specific version.

### Don't work in vendor

You should always be able to delete your `vendor` folder and run `composer install` without breaking your Cake app. So don't work inside that folder or edit anything in there, because you're changes aren't going to be kept. There are cases where you might want to debug files in there, or experiment with a package you're working on, but as I said. You should be able to delete it and recreate it easily.

### Custom code for `src`

If you want to add more PHP source code to your Cake app, and it's only going to be used by your Cake app. Place it under the `src` folder. You could called it `src/Lib/FooBar` and it takes on the namespace `App\Lib\FooBar`. No need to modify your `composer.json` file.

### Shared by plugins

If you want to have a library that is shared by all your `plugins`. Place it in the `plugins` folder and give it a name `plugins/FooBar`. You can add it to composer like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "FooBar\\": "./plugins/FooBar/src",
    }
},
```

It doesn't have to technically be a Cake plugin to be in that folder.

### Shared library

You can add a folder named `lib` which contains your different libraries, and add those to `composer.json` like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "FooBar\\": "./lib/FooBar",
    }
},
```